# Layout and Draw architecture on android

Tags: android

If I call a requestLayout() on a View, shouldn't it call invalidate() on the same View, forcing the view to be drawn after the layout recalculations are done?

Answer (score 0):

If the View changes size, it will be redrawn automatically. If the View remains the same size, invalidate is not called.